# Pagination Comments Doesn't Show

Tags: comments, pagination

what im trying to accomplish is adding a pagination to my function for comments. I think im on the right track with my code but I need some guidance.

```
<?php $comments = get_comments('number=24&amp;amp;status=approve');
$true_comment_count = 0;
foreach($comments as $comment) :
?>

<?php $comment_id = get_comment(get_comment_ID())->user_id; ?>
<?php $comment_type = get_comment_type(); ?>
<?php if($comment_type == 'comment') { ?>
<?php $true_comment_count = $true_comment_count +1; ?>
<?php $comm_title = get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID);?>
<?php $comm_link = get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID);?>
<?php $comm_comm_temp = get_comment($comment->comment_ID,ARRAY_A);?>
<?php $comm_content = $comm_comm_temp['comment_content'];?>

<li>

<span class="footer_comm_author">
<img width="170" height="150" class=" avatar user-<?php echo $comment_id ?>-avatar" alt="" src="http://deafcube.com/wp-content/plugins/user-avatar/user-avatar-pic.php?id=<?php echo $comment_id ?>">

<div class="comment-text"><a href="<?php echo($comm_link)?>" title="<?php comment_excerpt(); ?>"><?php echo($comment->comment_author)?></span> on 
<?php echo $comm_title?></a></div>

</li> 

<?php } ?>
<?php if($true_comment_count == 24) {break;} ?>
<?php endforeach;?>

<div id="pagination-comments"><?php paginate_comments_links($true_comment_count); ?></div>
```

THANK YOU ALL!

Comment: So, what's your actual **question**?

Comment: The pagination does show up, am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're passing arguments correctly to [`paginate_comments_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_comments_links). The function is basically a wrapper for [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), and accepts the same array of arguments.

Here are the defaults:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'base'         => '%_%',
        'format'       => '?page=%#%',
        'total'        => 1,
        'current'      => 0,
        'show_all'     => False,
        'end_size'     => 1,
        'mid_size'     => 2,
        'prev_next'    => True,
        'prev_text'    => __('&laquo; Previous'),
        'next_text'    => __('Next &raquo;'),
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'add_args'     => False,
        'add_fragment' =>  ''
    ); 
?>
```

Here's how I use it:

```
<?php paginate_comments_links( array( 'prev_text' => '&lt;&lt;', 'next_text' => '&gt;&gt;' ) ); ?>
```

So, what arguments are you trying to pass to the function?

Comment: $true_comment_count is what I am aiming for you can see that i have a if statement on it, how would I apply this to paginate_comments_links?

Comment: Just noticed my typo, the pagination does not show up, even with the default format.

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with `$true_comment_count`?

Comment: this makes the number of comments show, I could also take it out but i cant get the pagination to show at all

Comment: "*this makes the number of comments show*" - the `paginate_comments_links()` doesn't accept an argument that displays the number of comments. See the link for [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) from my answer.

Comment: i know but with or without that variable the paginate_comments_links does not show

Comment: Can you take out all of the `$true_comment_count` custom code, and just use a basic `wp_list_comments()` call, in order to track down where the problem is? I suspect that code is causing issues. You seem to be (unnecessarily) overriding WordPress core comment pagination functionality.

Comment: I put wp_list_comments and nothing gets returned, thats weird, is there a solution or a suggestion i should check into?

Comment: would this cause the problem if i made a page and used these functions on a page? I dont think thats the issue but I thought i would ask to narrow down the problem.

Comment: "*I put wp_list_comments and nothing gets returned*" - did you take out **all of the custom code**, so that you were just left with `wp_list_comments()`, `paginate_comments_links()`, etc.?

Comment: yes and the page came back with no results, if you like I can give you a link

Comment: "*yes and the page came back with no results, if you like I can give you a link*" - so, you get no results from *either* `wp_list_comments()` *or* `paginate_comments_links()`? You have something else going on here, I think. Can you post your entire `comments.php` in a Pastebin, or something?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/w3imFqEC